# Whether as a relative clause

Tags: nouns, whether

> I have serious questions whether this "died suddenly" thing has some kind of major [psyop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_operations_(United_States)#:%7E:text=Psychological%20operations%20(PSYOP)%20are%20operations,organizations%2C%20groups%2C%20and%20individuals.) angle to it now.

What is the function of the whether clause here?
Is it possible to state that whether in this sentence are used as relative clause defining "questions"?
Is it possible to put about before the whether so that whether clause can be seen as object of the preposition?

Answer (score 4):

The *whether*-clause is a closed interrogative content clause (finite subordinate yes/no question). Its main clause equivalent would be:

> Does this "died suddenly" thing have some kind of major psyop angle to
> it now?

These can be direct complements of the noun **question** immediately following the head noun, or an oblique complement contained inside a prepositional phrase headed by *as to*, *about*, *over*.

> By the 1990s, the change in the composition of the Supreme Court
> raised questions **as to** whether Roe v. Wade would be overruled.
> (Texas Law Review)
>
> It has raised questions **over** whether even a more limited security
> relationship between the two countries is even possible. (NYT)
>
> The disclosures have also raised questions **about** whether the
> F.B.I. funneled confidential information to Mr. Scarpa. (NYT)

Whereas relative clauses are allowed by all nouns and are hence modifiers, only certain nouns like   *reservations*, *discussion*, *argument* license ICCs as dependents, hence they are analyzed as complements.

Further, they are not relative clauses as they do not relativize any element of the subordinate clause, i.e. no element in the subordinate clause is understood through the head noun 'questions'.

In a relative clause there would always be something understood through the head noun. For example:

> He was the **man** [I met].

The subordinate clause is understood something like:

> I met **this man**.  (this man I'm talking about)

Comment: Yeah, _whether_ is just the _wh_-word for yes/no questions. _I don't know what he ate_ vs _I don't know whether he ate_. One embeds the question _What did he eat?_ and the other embeds the question _Did he eat?_. _Whether_ is required as complementizer. That's why it's often exchanged with _if_ -- only two choices, yes or no. As you say, this isn't a relative clause, it's a nominal complement, restricted to "picture nouns" to show the content.

Comment: Who says this: “These can be direct complements of the noun *question*”? I find *have questions whether* — without a preposition — to be unnatural.

Comment: _Serious questions_ sounds better with a _wh_-complement. It depends on whether the speaker takes _questions_ as a picture noun or not. It's somewhat marginal.

Comment: @TinfoilHat _The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_ p980 for one - they call them 'core complements'. It's quite a common occurrence if one looks around a bit, though specific instances may vary in acceptability according to the individual's ear.